# Did Moties from CoDominium influence the Tau from WH40k?

Tags: warhammer-40k, inspiration, codominium-universe

Tau and Moties seem  to share a suspiciously large amount of similarities, from their  specialisation into 'careers' to the origin of being a technologically advanced civilisation isolated due to stellar phenomenon.

I'm curious if Games Workshop have ever mentioned Niven and Pournelle's work as inspiration or if there are further similarities?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no direct connection between the two and it seems to me that any similarities between them are quite superficial.  The traits you mention are fairly generic sci-fi traits.

The primary differences of extreme Motie fecundity and ability to nearly instantly understand any technological device and ability to quickly reverse engineer it given even a minimal amount of investigation.  These would seem to be traits that may almost be "anti-Tau".

Comment: That sounds very Tau to me,  though I don't know *a lot* about them.